# Subscribes to a listener service of outlook for receive a notifications when calendar events change in Outlook.com

Tags: php, outlook-restapi

I need to subscribe to Outlook Calendar notifications for getting changes to Outlook on my server.  I've [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations#NotificationResource) and my code is mostly working fine but I'm stuck with the listener.

For notifications I

- First, create subscription
- On success, it'll return me a subscription id with other information
- After that when I made any changes in the calendar, it'll ping on my notification URL. BUT it doesn't give me which data was changed, it only gives me the following:

```
{
  "USER": "devapi",
  "HOME": "/home/devapi",
  "FCGI_ROLE": "RESPONDER",
  "QUERY_STRING": "",
  "REQUEST_METHOD": "POST",
  "CONTENT_TYPE": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "CONTENT_LENGTH": "1156",
  "SCRIPT_NAME": "/notification.php",
  "REQUEST_URI": "/notification.php",
  "DOCUMENT_URI": "/notification.php",
  "DOCUMENT_ROOT": "/home/ubuntu/www/devapi/api/web",
  "SERVER_PROTOCOL": "HTTP/1.1",
  "REQUEST_SCHEME": "https",
  "HTTPS": "on",
  "GATEWAY_INTERFACE": "CGI/1.1",
  "SERVER_SOFTWARE": "nginx/1.9.9",
  "REMOTE_ADDR": "000.000.00.000",
  "REMOTE_PORT": "62530",
  "SERVER_ADDR": "000.00.0.000",
  "SERVER_PORT": "443",
  "SERVER_NAME": "devapi.test.com",
  "REDIRECT_STATUS": "200",
  "SCRIPT_FILENAME": "/home/ubuntu/www/devapi/api/web/notification.php",
  "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT": "text/xml",
  "HTTP_CLIENTSTATE": "OutlookPush-56dfcd91df29c",
  "HTTP_HOST": "devapi.test.com",
  "HTTP_ODATA_VERSION": "4.0",
  "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH": "1156",
  "HTTP_CONNECTION": "Close",
  "PHP_SELF": "/notification.php",
  "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT": 1457516659.3082,
  "REQUEST_TIME": 1457516659
}
```

Comment: My quick google search turned up lots of result. Why didn't they work for you? What was the problem with those solutions? Where are you stuck?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434978/icalendar-invite-is-not-showing-rsvp-buttons-in-email-clients

Comment: Yes PeeHaa you right but actually i stuck with hotmail account it doesn't show me a rsvp buttons for an event invitation. but now i got the solution. i just made little chanhges in phpMailer file and its work for me as i expect.

Comment: Yes PeeHaa you right, it work fine but only my concern is with hotmail account it doesnt show me a rsvp buttons on event invitation. but after made some changes in phpmailer file it work for me as my expectation. Thank you